# Error in Coherence I am getting error in oracle coherence like "unable to convert type -28 to a Collection type

Tags: oracle-coherence

I am getting error in oracle coherence like "unable to convert type -28 to a Collection type" within the application when I refresh current cache

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue a while ago, and it's appeared that there was a bug in Coherence causing this error. It has been fixed by Oracle Coherence team, so it might be a case if you're running on an outdated version of the product.

Comment: Which Version of Coherence are  you using